# Multiprocessing with `Pool` throws error on M1 Macbook

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, apple-m1

On my Macbook Pro (Intel, 2020) I can successfully use `multiprocessing.Pool` like:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

p = Pool(8)
results = p.map(worker_function, list_of_inputs)
p.close()
```

However, if I run the same code on my Macbook Air (M1, 2020), I get a strange error repeated again and again (snippet below):

```markdown
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

Answer (score 12):

To solve this I first read [this blog post](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/python-multiprocessing/). The author explains the different ways that Python can start new threads, e.g. by *fork*-ing (basically copying the existing interpreter and most of its memory), *spawn*-ing new interpreters, and so on.

[In the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods), it appears that the default start method on OSX is *fork*. However, I noticed, that on my Macbook (M1, 2020), if I run:

```
import multiprocessing

multiprocessing.get_start_method()
```

I get `"spawn"`.

So I managed to **solve the problem** by explicitly declaring that I want the `"fork"` start method when creating the pool.

```
from multiprocessing import get_context

p = get_context("fork").Pool(8)
results = p.map(worker_function, list_of_inputs)
p.close()
```

---

## Update

Have you checked out [`ray`](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/)? It's faster and has a much cleaner API for multiprocessing. The above would simply be:

```
import ray
results = ray.get([worker_funtion.remote(inp) for inp in list_of_inputs])
```

Comment: Nice! Aside, today the linked documentation says for `spawn`: "Available on Unix and Windows. The default on Windows and macOS", hence matching what you already noticed. (Yes, macOS is referred to as Unix in that line, which in a way is true. But then `fork` says "The default on Unix". Oh well.)

Comment: Ah, only now I read a bit more in the documentation, and it also says "Changed in version 3.8: On macOS, the spawn start method is now the default. **The fork start method should be considered unsafe as it can lead to crashes of the subprocess.** See [bpo-33725](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/77906)."

Comment: I swear this wasted so much of my time... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Changing the context to `fork` as suggested above does resolve the issue, but you can still go around with `spawn`. Though I'm not an expert on this topic, my basic understanding on `Spawn` and `Fork` are that:

`Spawn`:

- Allocate new resources to a subprocess as needed without inheriting resources from the main process.
- Slow, but safe.

`Fork`:

- Share all the resources of the main process with the subprocess and start the process.
- Fast, but dangerous.

The under-the-hood `spawn` implementation of `multiprocessing` seems to execute the code multiple times. You can simply cover your code with `if __name__ == __main__` so that the code only spawns on the main process.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, get_context
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import time, os

def work_func(x):
    print("work_func:", x, "PID", os.getpid())
    time.sleep(1)
    return x**5

print("> Started, __name__:", __name__, "\tPID", os.getpid())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("os_count:", os.cpu_count())
    start = time.time()

    cpu = 4
    pool = get_context("spawn").Pool(cpu)
    print(pool.map(work_func, range(0, 10)))

    print("***run time(sec) :", time.time() - start)
```

gives:

```
> Started, __name__: __main__   PID 30380
os_count: 4
> Started, __name__: __mp_main__        PID 30382
work_func: 0 PID 30382
> Started, __name__: __mp_main__        PID 30383
work_func: 1 PID 30383
> Started, __name__: __mp_main__        PID 30384
work_func: 2 PID 30384
> Started, __name__: __mp_main__        PID 30385
work_func: 3 PID 30385
work_func: 4 PID 30382
work_func: 5 PID 30383
work_func: 6 PID 30384
work_func: 7 PID 30385
work_func: 8 PID 30382
work_func: 9 PID 30383
[0, 1, 32, 243, 1024, 3125, 7776, 16807, 32768, 59049]
***run time(sec) : 3.1123111248016357
```

while running with `fork` gives:

```
> Started, __name__: __main__   PID 380
os_count: 4
work_func: 0 PID 381
work_func: 1 PID 382
work_func: 3 PID 384
work_func: 2 PID 383
work_func: 4 PID 381
work_func: 6 PID 384
work_func: 5 PID 382
work_func: 7 PID 383
work_func: 8 PID 381
work_func: 9 PID 383
[0, 1, 32, 243, 1024, 3125, 7776, 16807, 32768, 59049]
***run time(sec) : 3.0129408836364746
```