# multiprocessing worker code not executing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have code like this:

```
def worker(data_row):
    print("In worker", data_row)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db_conn = init_db_conn()
    rows = db_conn.execute(query).fetchall()
    
    db_conn.close()

    pool = Pool(4)
    jobs = []
    for row in rows:
        print("In main", row)
        job = pool.apply_async(worker, (row,))
        jobs.append(job)

    for job in jobs:
        job.get()

    pool.join()
    pool.close()
```

When I execute this, only `In main` are printed, and zero `In worker`, so no worker code is executed. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the docs you have to call `close` before `join`.

[class multiprocessing.pool.Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool)

```
close()
    Prevents any more tasks from being submitted to the pool. 
    Once all the tasks have been completed the worker processes will exit.

terminate()
    Stops the worker processes immediately without completing 
    outstanding work. When the pool object is garbage collected 
    terminate() will be called immediately.

join()
    Wait for the worker processes to exit. 
    One must call close() or terminate() before using join().
```

Comment: That's true, but the code is not even executed till that point yet. I just tried to switch them and the program is still stuck

Comment: are you sure `rows` is not empty? works with something more simple: [https://onlinegdb.com/CbIbV3fas](https://onlinegdb.com/CbIbV3fas)

Comment: Yes, because if it is empty, I wouldn't see `In main` messages. I am using trino, python3 on Mac M1. Not sure that's the reason. I even tried your simple sample, and it gives me weird errors with a long stacktrace on the line `print(Pool())`

Comment: RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.

Comment: OK I found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67999590/1270003 It is related to Mac M1 after all... but I'll accept yours as thank you for your help